# I need to replace extra character from number (555) 564-8583 I want to allow plus sign and integer only

Tags: php, regex, string, str-replace

I have a string like (555) 564-8583 OR +91 (234) 5465-789 I want the result LIKE 5555648583 And another  one is like +912345465789

I want any PHP regex which allow only integer and plus sign only

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have tried 
     preg_replace('/[!@#$%^&*(), .?":{}|<>]/', '', $data['number']);
But its not filter the alphabets

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
[^\d\r\n+]+
```

Replace each match with a blank string

**[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Vjj57u/1)**

**Explanation:**

- `[^\d\r\n+]+` - matches 1+ occurrences of any character that is not a digit, not a newline, not a `+`

Comment: @Balwinder Please consider selecting it as the answer if it helped.